# Perl argument "user" isn't numeric in array element

Tags: arrays, perl, arguments, warnings, numeric

I always get the message that my argument in array isn't nummeric.
It happens 5 times in this little code:

```
    my $mcnamequery = "SELECT mcID FROM tblMCName WHERE mcName = '".$mcname."'";
$mcid = dbSelect($mcnamequery);
print $mcid->{mcID} . "\n";

my $userfsquery = "SELECT userFS FROM tblMcSubs WHERE mcFS = '".$mcid->{mcID}."'";  
my $execute = $dbh->prepare($userfsquery);
$execute->execute();

while (@usersfs = $execute->fetchrow_array()) {
    print $usersfs['userFS'] . "\n";

    my $mailquery = "SELECT useremail FROM tblUser WHERE userID = '".$usersfs['userFS']."'";
    $execute2 = $dbh->prepare($mailquery);
    $execute2->execute();
    while (@mails = $execute2->fetchrow_array()) {
        $counter++;
        print $mails['useremail']. "\n";
        if($counter == 1){
                $addresses = $mails['useremail'];
        }else{
            $addresses = $addresses. " " . $mails['useremail'];
        }   
    }   
}
```

The first time it happens, is in this line: `print $usersfs['userFS'] . "\n";`
After that, I receive this message everywhere where I want to use `$usersfs['userFS']` or `$mails['useremail']`

Error Messages:
Argument "userFS" isn't numeric in array element at /tem/obm/morningcheck/jantool.pl line 520.
Argument "userFS" isn't numeric in array element at /tem/obm/morningcheck/jantool.pl line 522.
Argument "useremail" isn't numeric in array element at /tem/obm/morningcheck/jantool.pl line 527.
Argument "useremail" isn't numeric in array element at /tem/obm/morningcheck/jantool.pl line 529.
Argument "useremail" isn't numeric in array element at /tem/obm/morningcheck/jantool.pl line 531.

Hopefully you can help me, thanks!

Comment: I know `fetchrow_array`, `fetchrow_arrayref` and `fetchrow_hashref` but not `fetchrow`. What does it do?

Comment: Maybe http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perlmysqlquery.php ?

Comment: Please don't link to the tiztag tutorial. It's horrible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print $mails['useremail']. "\n";
```

This is your problem. `[]` denote an array index, to an array called `@mails`. So a string arg is *never* valid.

Perhaps you mean:

```
print $mails{'useremail'}."\n";
```

Which is a key argument to a hash called `%mails`.

But as you're fetching an array called `@mails` ... you've either got to figure out the index, or otherwise make some key-value association.

Given both your queries fetch a single column, then you can simply access:

```
$mails[0]
```

and

```
$usersfs[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, arrays use numeric indices. `'userFS'` is not a number, hence the error.

If you want to use hash tables (also called associative arrays), you have to use curly brackets around the keys:

```
my %usersfs;
$usersfs{userFS} = "whatever";
```

Comment: Okey but I want to get the userFS from the database. How do I know, what number I have to insert then?

Comment: As you only fetch one column from the db, the result should be stored in the first element, i.e. `$usersfs[0]`.